# What is the difference between UNION and EXISTS filters in a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm experimenting with [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) and I've noticed a difference between to similar queries using either a UNION or a EXISTS filter.

```
SELECT (COUNT(?w1) as ?nbWriter) WHERE {
    ?w1 a dbo:Writer; 
    dbo:spouse ?w2 .
    FILTER ( EXISTS {?w2 a dbo:Writer} || EXISTS {?w2 a yago:AmericanNovelists.} )
}
```

produces result `nbWriters=371`

while query

```
SELECT (COUNT(?w1) as ?nbWriter) WHERE {
    ?w1 a dbo:Writer;
    dbo:spouse ?w2 .
    {?w2 a dbo:Writer.} 
    UNION
    {?w2 a yago:AmericanNovelists.} 
}
```

produces result `nbWriters=414`

Why is there a difference between these two queries ? Are they not equivalent (see previous question and answer [Proper way to add OR clause to SPARQL query](https://web.archive.org/web/20160814122326/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/22482/proper-way-to-add-or-clause-to-sparql-query)) ?

Comment: Please use a `DISTINCT` on `w1`, then both should return the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second query does not count *distinct* writers. For example, it counts [Robert Lowell](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Robert_Lowell) four times because:

1. his spouse [Lady Caroline Blackwood](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lady_Caroline_Blackwood) was a writer
2. his spouse [Jean Stafford](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jean_Stafford) was a writer
3. his spouse [Jean Stafford](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jean_Stafford) was an American novelist
4. his spouse [Elizabeth Hardwick](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elizabeth_Hardwick_(writer)) was an American novelist

But the first query is also incorrect, it counts Robert Lowell three times, because:

1. his spouse Lady Caroline Blackwood was a writer
2. his spouse Jean Stafford was a writer and an American novelist
3. his spouse Elizabeth Hardwick was an American novelist

Using `DISTINCT` on either query will give you the right answer (364):

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?w1) as ?nbWriter)
```

In general, to find what is the cause of an error in such queries, list all the results instead of just counting them.

Comment: Good diagnosis.  I'd have upvoted for the last sentence alone: a minute or two of debugging can save hours in asking questions and waiting for answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Joshua and svick are right, I should have made more testing before posting this question.